# Get all the lists on sub webs using javascript

Tags: 2010, list, client-object-model, properties, getsubwebs

I would like to know how to get subweb lists using CSOM.
I actually know how to get lists on a web and how to get a sub web collection but I can't figure out how to get lists on sub web collection.

Let's say we have the following web hierarchy.

```
http://www.web/web1
http://www.web/web2
http://www.web/...
```

How to iterate on web1, web2, etc and getting for example the list http://www.web/web42/Lists/myPrecious/.
?

I have been that far:

```
function displayLists() {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    webCollection = web.getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);
    context.load(webCollection);        
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, success), Function.createDelegate(this, error));
}

function success() {    
    var webEnumerator = webCollection.getEnumerator();  
    while (webEnumerator.moveNext())
    {           
        var web = webEnumerator.get_current();
        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("myPrecious");    
        var title = list != null ? list.get_title() : "nothing";            
        console.log(title);
    }           
}

function error(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

I'm getting the error

```
"The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested."
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to load and context.executequry() for getting list information of subweb.

Use below code in while loop.

```
function displayLists() {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    webCollection = web.getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);
    context.load(webCollection);        
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, success), Function.createDelegate(this, error));
}

function success() {    
    var webEnumerator = webCollection.getEnumerator();  
    while (webEnumerator.moveNext())
    {           
       var innercontext = webEnumerator.get_current();
     var  innerweb= innercontext.get_web();        
     var list = innerweb.get_lists().getByTitle("myPrecious");
     innercontext.load(list);
     innercontext.ExecuteQuery();
     var title = list != null ? list.get_title() : "nothing";            
     console.log(title);
    }           
}

function error(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: add 4 space or tab to have lines formatted as code. Not only reads better but improves SO search as well

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Unfortunetely I receive *cowebEnumerator is undefined*.

Comment: check edited answer

Comment: Thanks but now I have *Unable to get property 'undefined' of undefined or null reference*. Just by commenting all the script except the first line.

Comment: use above code...Have you use CSOM or JSOM?

Comment: I'm using only this code. Can I know which one of CSOM or JSOM it is ? *The object doesn't support property or method "get_web"*

Comment: Do you write code in Visual studio?

Comment: No I'm using notepad++ with encoded format UTF-8

Comment: ok and where you use this code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53678/discussion-between-ameliapond-and-sam).